# Can I trigger IBM/OpenWhisk functions with any trigger from any source?

Tags: triggers, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

In the documentation of IBM Cloud Functions, there is mentioned that the functions can be triggered with custom triggers: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-feeds_custom

This may be done via:
- WebHooks
- Polling
- Connections

What I have not been able to figure out from the docs: Are Connections and Polling only possible inside of the IBM Cloud ecosystem or generally usable with any service in any platform (e.g. a self-hosted database service)?

Answer (score 1):

Triggers can be fired from anywhere. The Apache OpenWhisk platform exposes a RESTful API to fire triggers using a HTTP POST request.

Comment: This would answer it for the case of WebHooks, right? So what about Polling and Connections?